I don't understand why/how Hashem's language seems opposite in Bereishis 2:16-17: אָכֹ֥ל תֹּאכֵֽל you may eat& then לֹ֥א תֹאכַ֖ל you may NOT eat?
I read the parshah over specifically trying to identify if Chava or the snake lied first.  I remember learning that if Adam and Chava hadn't sinned by eating the forbidden fruit that the snake would not have gained power over them (full force evil inclination) and rather would have become subrserviant to their good deeds.  When I read it it seems that the snake's first sentence (initially) opened the subject of Hashem's discussion but didn't actually slander Hashem directly or lie (yet).  The snake's words stimulated
Chava's by making a misleading statement but didn't actually say UNTRUE words (the DOUBLE negative mathmatically equates to Hashem's positive you CAN eat ALL....etc.)
Rereading it a few times in the text copied below, I noticed a seeming contradiction by HASHEM... I'm not sure how the second sentence doesn't contradict the first one like a lie.  If you "MAY EAT FROM ALL OF THE TREES" then how can the next sentence explain that one is forbidden??
Here is the actual Chumash text of those verses which I found: Chabad online tanach:
"16And the Lord God commanded man, saying, "Of every tree of the garden you may freely eat.     טזוַיְצַו֙ יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹהִ֔ים עַל־הָֽאָדָ֖ם לֵאמֹ֑ר מִכֹּ֥ל עֵֽץ־הַגָּ֖ן אָכֹ֥ל תֹּאכֵֽל:
17But of the Tree of Knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat of it, for on the day that you eat thereof, you shall surely die."        יזוּמֵעֵ֗ץ הַדַּ֨עַת֙ ט֣וֹב וָרָ֔ע לֹ֥א תֹאכַ֖ל מִמֶּ֑נּוּ כִּ֗י בְּי֛וֹם אֲכָלְךָ֥ מִמֶּ֖נּוּ מ֥וֹת תָּמֽוּת:"
I looked at the question(S) that were asked about this section of the Chumash on Mi Yodeya 5 years ago]2 but not neither of those questions specifically addressed the wording and context of H" words/ language which is what I'm inquiring about here.  My question in this case addresses ONLY the language in vs 16 vs. 17 with regards to Hashem's words only not the errors of Chava and/or the snake.
Related specifically to the WORDING and ORDER of the language of Chava and the snake which I looked to see how it was in line with the constant that H" encourages a person in the way they WANT to go, I suspected that Chava would have had to have been the FIRST one to say a lie to open the gate for the snake to go full scale into lie about who H" is and what H" said zone and noticed that at first the snake said his inquiry in the double negative (opposite of Hashem's positive) which only INFERS that a contradiction MAY exist but doesn't actually say that Hashem lied: in English the snake's statement would sound like "did Hashem NOT say that you can NOT eat from ALL of the trees in the Garden?"  The correct answer would be "no, H" said you CAN eat from all of the fruits in the Garden", so it seems to me that the snakes first attempt was only to stir the thought that Hashem MAY have lied but not actually saying that Hashem actually lied (which never happens - right?) But if Chava HAD answered with the English response above, how could she follow with a second statement which would indicate that ONE tree wasn't included in the "ALL TREES" specified previously - which is basically my whole issue.  Please help clear this up my understanding of these words if you can.

Look at the second definition of ו
: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.17?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%95&with=Lexicon&lang2=en

If I say “you can eat all the candy, but not the red ones”, did I somehow lie in one of the two clauses? Such a claim makes no sense. The second clause simply narrows the first one. This is true both intuitively and grammatically.

The ו prefix in Biblical Hebrew has a wider definition than that of “and” in English. Its essential function is to connect two words/clauses. That covers “and”, “but”, “insomuch as”, and more.

Thank you.  Well said and very much appreciated.  I pray for the day when the world will return to universally speak ONE Holy language.  Perhaps Babylon began this nightmare.

It seems to me that you understand the two verses as being independent items. Further as @Rabbi Kaii implies you understand the translation of the second verse to be

“and as for the tree of knowledge of good and bad, you must not eat of
it; for as soon as you eat of it, you shall die.”

The Torah is not written in verse form. In the Torah scroll verses are not delineated. There is no reason to see the two statements as  independent. This is to be seen in the Sefaria translation that has:

but as for the tree of knowledge of good and bad, you must not eat of
it; for as soon as you eat of it, you shall die.”

Note two items. [1] the verse does not begin with a capital letter; it is a continuation of the previous verse. [2] The conjunction וּ in the word וּמֵעֵ֗ץ is translated as “but”.
Thus we see that these two verses are really one statement. The second verse qualifies the statement in the first one. Thus there is no “seeming contradiction” in Hashem's words, chas vesholom.

A"Y, thank you for that. The idea that H" could contradict Himself is insane H"vS which is why I knew my question seemed valid.  That didn't make sense to me.   I appreciate your response but I am still questioning the language (separate or together regarding the words לֵאמֹ֑ר מִכֹּ֥ל עֵֽץ... it's probably a language issue; like most things.  How can the inferred "but" or two combined sentences concern change my understood meaning of כֹּ֥ל?  isn't כֹּ֥ל wholistic?  what allows for כֹּ֥ל to be modified with an exception?

It's a normal expression; for example - all the letters in this sentence are in lower case except the first one.

I appreciate the insightful answers but as an aside I felt judged for asking this question given that it was marked down 3 times.  Doesn't Torah teach that every question is a good question to ask?  I went out of my way to express that it Couldn't be that H" was wrong but that I was missing something so hmmmmmm.  Not sure how to respond to that overall

Respond to it by carrying on to ask and answer questions here and don't worry abolut a few downvotes.
